# add controller action into sonata page

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

How can I add custom action in sonata page bundle?

For example I have:

```
public function numberAction()
    {
        $number = random_int(0, 100);

        return new Response(
            '<div>Lucky number: '.$number.'</div>'
        );
    }
```

Now I want to add this action into page content, like you can see on the image. Is it possible? What is the best way to do that?

[image]